# SCIP Docker Image

Tags: docker, scip

Does anyone know of an SCIP docker image that also includes python 3.9+?

I have found [this one](https://www.pokutta.com/blog/pages/scip/scip-teaching.html), but it runs on python 3.7.
I basically need a docker image that can run this:

```
from pyomo.environ import ConcreteModel, Var, Objective, Constraint, SolverFactory, NonNegativeReals, minimize

model = ConcreteModel()
model.x = Var(within=NonNegativeReals)
model.obj = Objective(expr=model.x, sense=minimize)
solver = SolverFactory('scip')
result = solver.solve(model)
print(model.x())
```

Answer (score 0):

What you actually need is pyomo to run that code - the Python version is probably not that important.

Furthermore, the SCIP version included in the docker container in the linked article is outdated. The container image is apparently not maintained anymore. My recommendation is to use conda to install SCIP and PySCIPOpt in a local environment and then install pyomo:

```
conda create --name scip --channel conda-forge python=3.11 pyscipopt pyomo
```